# "Declaration expected" in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to vbscript. I get the error

> Declaration expected at get_html

At the bottom part of my code. I am actually trying to declare a value (which is a url) for the variable `get_html`. How can I resolve this?

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

End Sub
Sub get_html(ByVal up_http, ByVal down_http)
    Dim xmlhttp : xmlhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.3.0")
    xmlhttp.open("get", up_http, False)
    xmlhttp.send()

    Dim fso : fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    Dim newfile : newfile = fso.createtextfile(down_http, True)
    newfile.write(xmlhttp.responseText)

    newfile.close()

    newfile = Nothing
    xmlhttp = Nothing

End Sub
get_html _"http://www.somwwebsite.com", _"c:\downloads\website.html"

End Module
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some syntax mistakes.

- Module statement is not part of [**VBScript**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw9cadb%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- Underscores can lead to unexpected results. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198844.aspx (search for the word `underscore` on page)
- You can't use parentheses when calling a Sub *(e.g. `xmlhttp.open` is a sub, does not return anything)*. You have two main alternatives to calling a sub routine. `sub_proc param1, param2` or `Call sub_proc(param1, param2)`
- The assignment operator '`=`' is not enough for the objects. You should
  use [**Set**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) statement. It assigns object references to the
  variables.

The response may be return as utf-8 encoded. But however FSO is not at peace with utf-8. Another option is to write the response as unicode (passing `True` as third parameter to [**CreateTextFile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018%28v=vs.60%29.aspx))
   but the output size will be larger than it should be. Therefore I would prefer to use [**Stream**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object.
I've revised your code. Please consider.

```
'Requeired Constants
Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1 'only creates if not exists
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2 'overwrites or creates if not exists
Const adTypeBinary = 1

Sub get_html(ByVal up_http, ByVal down_http)
    Dim xmlhttp, varBody
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.3.0")
        xmlhttp.open "GET", up_http, False
        xmlhttp.send
        varBody = xmlhttp.responseBody
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    Dim str
    Set str = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        str.Type = adTypeBinary
        str.Open
        str.Write varBody
        str.SaveToFile down_http, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        str.Close
    Set str = Nothing
End Sub

get_html "http://stackoverflow.com", "c:\downloads\website.html"
```

Comment: i get this error can't use parentheses when calling a Sub, what do i do to fix it, pls help i am a beginner

Comment: `code` Sub_proc get_html(ByVal up_http, ByVal down_http) is it like this?

Comment: It is just "calling a sub" syntax sample and `sub_proc` is only a sample sub name.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to move your call to `get_html` to be a call from within your `Main` subroutine (`Sub Main()`).  For example:

```
Sub Main()
  get_html _"http://www.somwwebsite.com", _"c:\downloads\website.html"
End Sub
```

AFAIK, you can't make function calls from directly within a module.

Comment: i get this error : Argument not specified for parameter 'down_htttp of Public Sub get_html(up_http As Object, down_http As Object)'. after changing the code like you said. Thanks for your help